# Apply blending mode on views without specifying colors

Tags: iphone, objective-c, drawing, core-graphics, alphablending

I am creating an drawing application, I need to add blending modes functionality in my app.
What I am doing is drawing my circle through core graphics and many other shapes are drawn .I want to add blending effect in the app like shown in the image:-

[image]

My background view of the shapes in clear clear and code for drawing circle is like :-

```
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [ [UIColor colorWithRed:244.0/255.0 green:19.0/255.0 blue:33.0/255.0 alpha:1] CGColor]);
CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeDifference);
CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 0, 0);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 40, 40);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 0, 40);
CGContextClosePath(context);
CGContextFillPath(context);
```

But when adding multiple circle view they are not showing effect like shown in the above image.

I looked at the quartz demo code which has blending option, it in that code, they are achieving by setting colors for source and background.

But in my case I do not want to provide any colors option, and more my background is clear color.

Please provide me if what I am thinking is possible or not.

Please provide any suggestions on how can I achieve this.

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.